# defining php executable location in aptana studio 3

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, aptana

i want to use aptana studio 3 but when i run any project a window appears that says

select a way to run file.php which has two options php script and php server.

When i select PHP Script it shows a window The current debugger does not have any defined php executables. Please define a php executable location before continuing

And a window appears that has option for adding new php interpreters.

Can anybody tell me how to do this configuration?

i am using ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

On the window that appears click on the search button and go to the PHP folder. Click Ok and Aptana will find the executable.